# longest sequence of consecutive divisors of an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

today I saw this question on Codeforces : given an integer n, find the maximum count of consecutive divisors of n , for example if n=40 , the divisors of n are [1,2,4,5,8,10,20,40] , the answer is 2 which corresponds to [4,5] .I tried to answer this naively , by decomposing the integer into primes and finding all its divisors from the combination of those primes , then find the largest sequence of consecutive divisors :the problem is even if this works it takes a lot of times (up to 2 minutes).After looking to other people answers I realized this : the longest sequence of divisors of n has a length equal to length of D=[1,....,a], where D are consecutive divisors of n , for example for 40 D=[1,2] so answer is 2, My question is how to prove that there is no other sequence longer than D ? thanks for ur patience reading this

Comment: Hint: For any positive integers $n,k$, there is some multiple of $k$ in the list $n, n+1, n+2, \ldots, n+k-1$

Comment: Besides 1,2, note 4,5 are also consecutive divisors of 40. Did you just exclude those since 1,2 is same length? If you didn't already search the whole list of divisors, is there some way you knew in advance for 40 there would not be a sequence of length more than 2?

Comment: @coffeemath it's given by the authors of the question , so probably they checked that (or there is some proof for it )

Comment: @BrianMoehring can you elaborate more ? I still cant figure it out

Comment: Try an example: let's say your number $n$ is divisible by all of $7,8,9,10$. Convince yourself that it is also divisible by all of $1,2,3,4$ (e.g because $1\mid 7\mid n, 2\mid 8\mid n,3\mid 9\mid n,4\mid 8\mid n$. (Symbol $\mid$ means "divides".) Now try to generalize.

Comment: @StinkingBishop but is the converse true ? if 1 | n and 2 | n and 3 |n , how are we sure that there is no other longer than 3 sequence of consecutive numbers that divides n ?

Comment: If there was one (say $26,27,28,29$) then one of those four numbers would be divisible by $1$, one would be divisible by $2$, one would be divisible by $3$ and one would be divisible by $4$. Thus, you would have also $1,2,3,4$ as divisors.

Comment: The generalization is hinted at in @BrianMoehring 's comment: if you find any $k$ consecutive divisors, then $1,2,3,\ldots,k$ will also be consecutive divisors.

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks I see it now

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be a positive integer.

We want to prove that, whenever $k$ consecutive integers (say $m, m+1, m+2,\ldots, m+k-1$) divide a positive integer $n$, then the (consecutive) integers $1,2,3,\ldots, k$ must *also* divide $n$.

Notice that, whenever you have any $i$ consecutive integers ($i$ - a positive integer), *at least one is divisible by $i$*. (In fact, *exactly* one, but we won't use that.)

So, if $1\le i\le k$, one of $m, m+1, m+2, \ldots, m+i-1$ will be divisible by $i$. Say, it is $m+j$ for some integer $j, 0\le j<i$, However, *that* number $m+j$ is one of those $k$ consecutive integers dividing $n$ above (due to $j<i\le k$). Thus, $i$ divides $m+j$ and $m+j$ divides $n$. By transitivity of divisibility, it follows that $i$ divides $n$. As this is valid for all $i, 1\le i\le k$, it follows that $n$ is divisible by all of $1,2,3,\ldots, k$.

Now, all this implies that you cannot have $k$ consecutive divisors of $n$ without also having $1,2,3,\ldots, k$ divide $n$. In other words, the maximum count of consecutive integers dividing $n$ is already realised on the consecutive numbers starting with $1$. That enables the simplification of the algorithm as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -3):

If $k! | n$ then $n$ has $k$ consecutive divisors.

So the even numbers have two or more consecutive divisors. The multiples of $3! = 6$ have three or more, the multiples of $4! = 24$ have four or more, and so on.

The converse is false: $12$ has four consecutive divisors $1,2,3,4$.

A partial converse settles $n=40$:
if $n$ has $k$ consecutive divisors then $n$ must be a multiple of  each prime  $p \le k$ since one of the divisors is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: The converse is false.  You need to rewrite the argument with the lcm in place of the product.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Fixed, thanks. Feel free to edit or answer if you see the correct converse.

Comment: If $k!|n,$ then $n$ has **at least** $k$ consecutive divisors, see $k=5, n=60.$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Edited to fix the false claim. Thanks.

Comment: @EthanBolker so if k!|n there is k or more consecutive divisors ?so if k the maximum possible value, are we not sure that there are exactly k consecutive divisors ?

Comment: This question really has very little to do with divisibility by $k!$. It is really saying that $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,\ldots k)\mid\operatorname{lcm}(n,n+1,n+2,\ldots,n+k-1)$.

Comment: Yes, if $k! | n$  there are at least $k$ consecutive divisors. But the maximum such $k$ does not provide the answer. Several commenters pointed that out and I fixed my answer.